# How to run a simple 'Hello World' PHP script on Heroku?

Tags: php, git, heroku

I want to run a simple 'Hello World' PHP script to start understanding how Heroku functions in general. So I have created a git repository at Github with a simple 'Hello World' php script and an empty README file.  Therefore the source code in the php file is:

```
<?php

echo 'Hello World';

?>
```

I applied step-by-step the instructions at Heroku:

1. I downloaded the Heroku CLI
2. entered `heroku login` and my credentials at the command line
3. had php, composer and git installed
4. entered `git clone *my_git_repository_adress*`
5. entered `cd *my_git_repository_name*`
6. entered `heroku create`

However, when I enter `git push heroku master` at the command line I get the following error: `App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php.git`.

Then when I try to set the buildpack by entering `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php`, I get the following error:

```
 ▸    Missing required flag:
 ▸    -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 ▸    See more help with --help
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell to Heroku that it's a PHP project. So run into your folder:

```
$ echo '{}' > composer.json
$ git add composer.json
$ git commit -m "add composer.json for PHP app detection"
```

or you can set your buildpacks manually:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php
```

And push again.
Hope I help!

Comment: Thank you for your response. See my edited post above. I have tried to do this and I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku needs `index.php` to detect the [buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/bin/detect). It seems you are just using single `Hello World.php`.

Try renaming the file or create an  `index.php` and add [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/768472/5447994) to your desired page.

Comment: Thank you for your response. To start with, you are probably right about naming the php script as index.php but I think that it also requires to add other files like composer.json (github.com/heroku/php-getting-started).

Comment: Secondly, can you be a bit more clear about what do you mean as my desired webpage? I thought that my 'Hello World' app will be hosted and presented in Heroku so I do not have to redirect it at any page...

Comment: Regarding your first comment - Since you have mentioned - _#3 had php, composer and git installed_ thought that you have `composer.json` already

Comment: _desired page_ - Something like `Hello World.php`. BTW - I haven't mentioned _desired webpage_

Comment: Ok finally it run even though I did not have a composer.json in my git (however I got a warning about it). I am going to write how I did in detail later. Ok sorry about the webpage but when you are using the term page I am instantly reading it as webpage.